# How many grams is "1 package" of stuffing mix?

Tags: stuffing, meatloaf

This [meatloaf recipe video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eQgyUTxpIw&t=38s) calls for 1 package of stove top stuffing mix.
Some stove top boxes are [170 grams](https://d2d8wwwkmhfcva.cloudfront.net/800x/d2lnr5mha7bycj.cloudfront.net/product-image/file/large_7ed68f23-579c-45c2-a7ec-95adef8761c1.jpg) 
others are [120 grams](https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Enlarge/150/558/150558.jpg) 
Is there a size that is more common than the others?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

(IMO) I don't think it should make a huge difference in such a recipe.

The recipe you link use the chicken one which is 170g.

If you only have access to the other one (120g turkey) , just get 2 boxes and mix enough to make 170g.

To answer your question, they should both be more or less common in regular supermarket ?